# Использование jQuery на сервере и на локалке

Tags: jquery

Не совсем понимаю в подключении jQuery, сейчас последняя версия 3.2.1, но на сервере просят подключить 1.11.1 - у них настолько старая версия или я чего-то не понимаю ? Подскажите пожалуйста почему у них такая версия

Comment: А разве jQuery работает на сервере, а не в браузере у пользователя!?

Comment: jQuery не имеет никакого отношения к серверу.

Comment: Логично, я просто не понимаю, я подключил jQuery последней версии, но заказчик просит переподключить на 1.11.1 - и я так подозреваю карусели все полетят и вопрос кто не прав в этой ситуации?) И почему от меня хотят 1.11.1 а не последнюю версию ?

Comment: То самое чувство, когда заказчик рассказывает как надо писать код

Comment: подключи еще 1.11.1 и мигрейт 
но сама версия ниже jquery 2.х.х для браузеров ниже 9 ie т.д.

Comment: @РашенБеар то чувство, когда исполнитель не знает, что он делает))

Comment: что за "мигрейт" ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и то правда

Answer (score 3):

На сегодняшний день JQuery предлагает три стабильных версии:

- 3.2.1 - самая свежая, на сегодняшний день, версия, в которой убраны старые костыли для IE и использованы современные Web API. По сути - это импрув версии 2.x
- 2.2.4 - предыдущая улучшенная версия, в которой вырезана поддержка IE 6/7/8
- 1.12.4 - Более тяжелая версия, но с поддержкой IE 6/7/8

Таким образом, если заказчик хочет поддерживать старые версии IE, его выбор в пользу 1.x понятен, хотя и может быть подвергнут критике с точки зрения бизнеса. С 12 января 2016 года компания Microsoft прекратила поддержку старых версия IE. Соответственно, пользователи могут использовать их только на свой страх и риск. Производителям ПО нет практического смысла поддерживать старые версии, т.к. многие современные методы просто не возможно реализовать для них. Однако, бывают ситуации, когда ПО рассчитано на конкретного пользователя(ей), например закрытый корпоративный ресурс для офиса, где все еще стоит IE8.

Так же, для перехода на jQuery 3.x был разработан специальный плагин [jQuery Migrate 3.0](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate#migrate-older-jquery-code-to-jquery-30)